# Can JaVers track changes to JavaFX model classes using observable properties?

Tags: java, javafx, gson, javers

I'm working on a JavaFX application where our model objects all use observable object values.  We're also using EclipseLink MOXY to serialize several of the models to XML files so storing values in `ObjectProperty<T>` is required given that the output of a property with a null value omits the tag (*a desired feature*).  We're also looking for a way to track changes to several of the model objects and have begun looking into JaVers but are running into some issues.

Because JaVers uses GSON under the hood, we've been unable to successfully use it successfully.  It looks like GSON has issues reconstructing model classes using observable properties.  Here's a quick example model class:

```
class Demo {

    private ObjectProperty<String> someProp =
        new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "someProp");

    public Demo(String someProp) {
        this.someProp.setValue(someProp);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<String> somePropProperty() {
        return someProp;
    }

    @Id
    public String getSomeProp() {
        return someProp.getValue();
    }

    public void setSomeProp(String someProp) {
        this.someProp.setValue(someProp);
    }
}
```

Here's how we might try and use JaVers with this model class (*Note: I didn't include any of the JAXB annotations*)...

```
Javers javers = JaversBuilder
    .javers()
    .withMappingStyle(MappingStyle.BEAN)
    .build;

Demo demo = new Demo("one");

javers.commit("test", demo);

demo.setSomeProp("two");

javers.commit("test", demo);

JqlQuery query = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId("one", Demo.class).build();

// this throws runtime exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to 
// invoke public javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty() with no args
List<Shadow<Demo>> shadows = javers.findShadows(query);
```

Analyzing the stack trace leads me to believe that its GSON causing the issues.  The very top of the trace has:
`at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:111)`

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the `@Id` should be on the property method? If Javers isn't a JavaFX aware library I think it should be at the getter method. The property method returns a `ObjectProperty<String>`, which is an interface and cannot be instantiated. btw. `ObjectProperty<String>` can be replaced by `StringProperty` (and `SimpleStringProperty` as concrete implementation).

Comment: @M.leRutte good catch.  It was supposed to be on the getter so I fixed it.  Interesting point about the `ObjectProperty<T>` being an interface.  I hadn't thought about that.  The reason I'm using an `ObjectProperty<String>` is because the `SimpleStringProperty` (_in my experience_) handles null values in a way that doesn't work for this application.  If you set it to null, it returns "" which doesn't work for our application.  Because I'm persisting these object using JAXB, I need the null values because the represent a non-existent tag (as opposed to an empty tag with no contents).

Comment: AFAIK `SimpleStringProperty` *only* returns `""` when using [`getValueSafe()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html#getValueSafe--) *if the value is `null` an empty String is returned instead.*

Comment: That's exactly my point.  I need `null` if the value is null, not the empty string.  Perhaps I'll have to roll my own solution so GSON has a concrete class to construct instead of an interface.

Comment: `getValue()` will return `null`, if you return that in your getter method then it will do what you need.

Comment: OK, Joe, I will try to solve this using custom type adapters, give me a while

Answer (score 0):

If `ObjectProperty` is a kind of wrapper to your domain/model objects, I believe it should be removed before passing to JaVers. JaVers should work with clean domain objects. See https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#ignoring-things.
The similar problem is solved by Hibernate unproxy hook, see:
https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#hibernate-unproxy-hook

Does this solutions is can be used in your case?